# Make an image bigger respecting original proportions Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

If I have an image like this :

```
Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset( //this image
              file,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          _buildContents(),
        ],
      ),
```

And I want to have this image 1.5x times or 1.2x times bigger (or smaller) without exceeding
in width or height, how can I do? (Keeping original proportions safe).

Comment: try BoxFit.contain or BoxFit.cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use remove `fit: BoxFit.fill` since it'll distort the image as per the documentation:

> BoxFit.fill: Fill the target box by distorting the source's aspect
> ratio.

You can safely scale the image using `Transform.scale` inside the Column such as:

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.50,
  child: Image.asset(
    file,
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the **scale** property of Image.asset()

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **LayoutBuilder** widget and depending on the constraint that provides the LayoutBuilder widget specify the size your image